# Passing ServerResponse by parameter in Express

Tags: node.js, express, http

I want to set some cookies from the Express server, but I want to do it in a function. I'm not sure about what is internally http ServerResponse, but if I set a header inside the function, that header is not available outside it. E.g, in handler

```
mySetHeader(res);
// if I check res here there is NO header

function mySetHeader(res) {
   res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', serialize('my-cookie', 'my-cookie-value', { path: '/' }));
}
```

On the other hand if I return res, it works

```
res = mySetHeader(res);
// if I check res here there IS a header

function mySetHeader(res) {
   res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', serialize('my-cookie', 'my-cookie-value', { path: '/' }));
   return res;
}
```

I have looked quickly for some examples where res is passed to a function, but I haven't found much.  I wonder if this is an acceptable pattern or if I should do this in another way. Maybe through a middleware or something

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```js
function mySetHeader(res) {
  res.setHeader("A", "B");
}
app.use(function(req, res) {
  mySetHeader(res);
  res.end();
})
```

The header is set as expected.

Perhaps you need to share more of your code.

Comment: thanks for your reply  The question is wrong. In fact I was overwriting the cookies somewhere else. I would remove the question but I can't.